# Change window size PHPUnit Selenium2TestCase

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I need to maximize my window when the test start and I found this [Class `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Window`](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/class-PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Window.html#m_maximize).

So I tried to use the method `$this->maximize()` but I only get

> BadMethodCallException: The command 'maximize' is not existent or not supported
>   yet.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Well, you tried that - with which backend?

Comment: Is this connected to a specific web-browser? I guess you get the exception because the driver tells you that it is not supported. So change the driver that support is added. Consult the selenium development information how to extend selenium and add missing features. It might be that you also need to change the browser that is driven by the driver as well so that this is possible.

Comment: Well I got the file window.php in my directory so the phpunit version I use support it, right now I use the chrome driver I also tried with firefox don't work there either.

Comment: You need to use a driver that supports it or add the missing feature to the drivers you use: Chrome, Firefox. Please understand that Stackoverflow does not work well for *Feature Requests*, consult the vendor of the software for your feature requests. The PHP file only wraps the interface, the implementation is in the driver. You see the error message because the driver tells you no such method exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On selenium2TestCase v1.3.3 it's

```
$this->prepareSession()->currentWindow()->maximize();
```