# How to maximize Firefox dimensions with PHPUnit Selenium WebDriver

Tags: php, firefox, selenium, webdriver, phpunit

So I've been wondering how I set the browser dimensions to a certain point.
But then I realized I might be switching screens etc..

So is there anything that I can do to make my browser maximize the screen no matter what resolution it has?
Or do I always have to give a certain height / width? Also would it be better to go to a certain URL first or is it better to set dimensions before doing anything?

Currently trying it on a Mac in Firefox.
Using PHPUnit Selenium WebDriver.( From Sebastian Bergmann )

I tried using:

```
 $this->currentWindow()->maximize();
```

But it didn't work, I had the error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method TestCore::currentWindow()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change window size PHPUnit Selenium2TestCase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099243/change-window-size-phpunit-selenium2testcase)

Comment: I saw that one but: $this->currentWindow()->maximize();
didn't work for me

Comment: Ah, okay. I've never used PHP in my life, so I'm just going off Google searches and what I can glean from the [confusing-looking documentation](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/class-PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Window.html) :)

Comment: Whoever linked the other issue, it doesn't solve it for me ;/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with PHPUnit 4.1.0 and selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0

```
$this->windowMaximize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same issue. I wanted it to be maximized for all my tests in a particular class.

I solved it by overriding setUpPage and using $this->currentWindow()->maximize()

So that the test class looks like this:

```
class licensingTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{

    public function setUpPage()
    {
         $this->currentWindow()->maximize();
    }

}
```

I'm using:

- Selenium 2 WebDriver (PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase)
- PHPUnit 4.6.4
- selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar